# Environment variable changed

Tags: linux, hostname, centos-6

At first my hostname was `localhost.localdomain` in CentOS 6.2

I installed ubuntu in separate partition after that my hostname was changed to this
`###-###-###-###-####.####.example.com`

In /etc/sysconfig/network of CentOS it shows hostname as

`NETWORKING=yes`

`HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain`

But while running `env` command it showing hostname as 
`HOSTNAME=###-###-###-###-####.####.example.com`

now what should I do to change my hostname to localhost.localdomain

Comment: See the `hostname` command.

Comment: now its working fine I edited hostname in ubuntu and After restarting here(CentOS) also its changed, now while running hostname command its showing the output as localhost.localdomain